# How to display the last attribute order by 'created_at' in laravel view

Tags: php, eloquent, request, laravel-8

I have `liste.blade.php`a liste that contains all the `candidats` and their informations. For each `candidat` **I need to display all the data of only his last `candidature`**

**Question** :

How can I show all the columns of **only** the **last** `candidature`  of each `candidat` ?

`Candidat Model` :

```
     protected $fillable = [
    'service_id',
    'demande',
    'nom',
    'telephone',
    'cin',...
    ];

public function candidatures()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Candidature::class);
}
```

`Candidature Model`

```
  protected $fillable = [
    'candidat_id',
    'doc',
    'date_depot',
    'etat',
    'demande',
    ];

public function candidat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Candidat::class, 'candidat_id');
}
```

`Candidat controller` :

```
 public function index()
{
   $candidat = Candidat::join('candidatures', 'candidatures.candidat_id', '=', 'candidats.id')
                ->whereNotIn('etat', ['Archivé', 'Refusé'])
                ->where('candidats.deleted','false')
                ->select('candidats.*)
                ->get();

    return view('candidat.liste', compact('candidat'));

  }
```

`liste.blade.php`:

```
     @foreach($candidat as $key => $data)
    <tr>
        <th>$data->id</th>
        ...
        @foreach($data->candidatures as $candidature)
            <td>{{$candidature->demande  }}</td>
            <td>{{$candidature->date_depot}}</td>
            <td>{{$candidature->etat}}</td>
        @endforeach  
    @endforeach
```

Ps: I have to submit my project today

Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 1):

Here You can use Order By clause and sort in dese to get last record

```
$candidat = Candidat::join('candidatures', 'candidatures.candidat_id', '=', 'candidats.id')
                ->whereNotIn('etat', ['Archivé', 'Refusé'])
                ->where('candidats.deleted','false')
                ->select('candidats.*)
                ->orderBy('candidatures.id','desc')
                ->limit(1)
                ->get();
```

Comment: should I also delete  @foreach($data->candidatures as $candidature) in `liste.blade.php` ?

Comment: I did what you said, but I got the the values, last and new one, so I deleted foreach function but I got "Property [demande] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: Try to use key value pair in foreach like ```foreach($data->candidatures as $key => $candidature)```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have relationships defined you can use

`Candidat::with('candidatures')` instead of `Candidat::join('candidatures', 'candidatures.candidat_id', '=', 'candidats.id')` or even ->candidatures like

```
$candidats = Candidat::all();
```

And in `foreach ($candidats as $candidat)` run `$candidat->candidatures()->latest()->first()`

Comment: But i don't want all the candidates to be showen

Comment: also please how can I get to candidature using `$candidat->candidatures()->latest()->first()`

Comment: I added it in `liste.blade.php` and got this error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::candidatures does not exist.

Comment: `liste.blad.php` is a liste that contains candidats and their candidature informations, there is a candidate in each line